# Unable to set date and time in AntD React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, momentjs, antd

I have an AntD form in React. For the a particular use case, I am resuing the form to just show values in view mode.

I am able to set the text fields using

```
form.setFieldsValue({

title : 'Hello',
dob : moment("12/09/2025").format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
time : moment("10:55").format("HH:MM")

})
```

The date picker element in my form looks something like :

```
‹DatePicker
key='startdate'
name='startdate'
mode='date'
placeholder='Select Start Date'
format='DD/MM/yyyy'
allowClear={false}
disabledDate={(current) =› current.isBefore(moment ().subtract(1,
"day") )}
style={{ width:
'100%' }}
onChange={ (value) =>
I
handleDate({ target: { value, name:
"startdate" } })}

/>
```

The title field gets set but the dob and time doesn't get updated.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: are you using datepicker to set dob?

Comment: I am just trying to add the date in the form field values. Do I have to do anything extra to update the UI?

And yes, I am using the DatePicker to set dates in my form.

Comment: can you please update the question with form content as well.

Comment: @SiddharthBagal Added the snippet